# PHP Carbon change date to current year (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a simple way using carbon to change a date string to the current year? I need it to display a birthday in my calendar. I currently am doing the following in my blade view:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate('Y-m-d', $contact->birthdate)->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

The question is, how can I change the year to the current year? I have been playing around with this from the docs:

```
$xmasThisYear = Carbon::createFromDate(null, 12, 25);  // Year defaults to current year
```

But I do not know how to change the year from an existing date string. The following for example does not work:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate('m-d', $contact->birthdate)->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: probably make 1 object with the birthday and new object now and set day and month from the birthday?

Comment: Actually just fixed it really simply by using this: `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($contact->birthdate)->year(now()->format('Y'))->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After posting the question I figured it out, I can simply do the following:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contact->birthdate)->year(now()->format('Y'))->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

`->year(now()` simply changes the year to the current year.